# node js remove a field from the returning json

Tags: json, node.js

From what is returned in the following `JSON`, I need to remove the attribute called `password`. I already tried the following code but it didn't work. Look at the comment where I have added the code.

```
app.post('/my/user',function(req,res){
    var user = req.body;

    User.addUser(user, function(err,users){
        if(err){
            throw err;
        } else {
                delete users['password']; // THIS IS WHERE I ADDED MY CODE. BUT IT DOESN'T WORK

            res.json({users, status: "SUCCESS" });
        }

    })
});
```

Comment: Is `users` an array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be using Mongoose, in which case you first need to convert the resulting document to a regular JS object before you can remove any of its properties:

```
var userObj = users.toObject();
delete userObj.password;

res.json({ users : userObj, status: "SUCCESS" });
```

More information on `Document.toObject()` [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject).